# How do I resolve intersecting operatorgroups providing the same APIs?

Tags: openshift, redhat, operator-lifecycle-manager

On my cluster, an alert has been firing for a while now; "CsvAbnormalFailedOver2Min". This is due to a csv (devspacesoperator.v3.10.0) failing as a result of 'intersecting operatorgroups providing the same APIs'.

I understand that, according to the OLM docs, "each time an active member CSV syncs, OLM queries the cluster for the set of intersecting provided APIs between the CSV’s OperatorGroup and all others. OLM then checks if that set is the empty set." In my case, the set is not empty and the CSV’s provided APIs are not a subset of the OperatorGroup’s.

Each example of this issue I can find online, including the only RedHat solutions article I can find related to it, appears to be caused by a user wishing to install two versions of the same operator in different namespaces. In my case however, I only want to install one version of the operator, and am unable to do so because the OLM operator is finding intersecting operatorgroups providing the same APIs somewhere.

The installModes of the devspacesoperator.v3.10.0 csv are shown below:

```
installModes:
  - supported: false
    type: OwnNamespace
  - supported: false
    type: SingleNamespace
  - supported: false
    type: MultiNamespace
  - supported: true
    type: AllNamespaces
```

Does anyone have an idea as to how I can resolve this or can help me understand more about the issue?

Comment: Check if there are multiple OperatorGroups in your cluster that might be providing the same APIs. use `kubectl get operatorgroup -A` this will show you the OperatorGroups across all namespaces. Use `kubectl/oc describe operatorgroup <operatorgroup-name> -n <namespace>`  to ensure there are no conflicting or duplicate APIs. Additionally fetch the information about the `devspacesoperator.v3.10.0` CSV using `kubectl get csv -n <namespace> devspacesoperator.v3.10.0 -o yaml` and look for  the `spec.customresourcedefinitions.owned` section to see which APIs it is providing.

Comment: One more thing, check OLM logs for any additional information or errors that might provide insights into the issue use `oc logs -n olm deploy/olm-operator`